# Ignoring NA in R across multiple columns of Datafrme using na.omit or NA.RM and mapply

Tags: r, na, mapply

I have a dataframe that looks somethings like this:

```
 SampleNo Lab1  Lab2  Lab3 lab4    lab5    lab6    lab7   lab8    lab9   lab10 
1  59.84    60.59   60.39   60.29   60.19   60.32   60.24   60.3    60.43   NA
2  59.78    60.19   60.16   60.23   60.32   60.46   60.53   60.2    60.40   59.6
3  59.86    60.17   60.22   60.28   60.18   60.42   60.21   60.0    60.44   NA 
4  59.85    60.42   60.28   60.31   60.19   60.41   60.54   60.2    60.48  59.7 
5  59.97    60.79   60.30   60.26   60.40   60.47   60.52   60.0    60.46   59.7
6  60.03    60.26   60.36   60.21   60.32   60.46   60.50   60.1    60.29   60.0
```

I would like to sum the squares of each column in the dataframe whilst ignoring NA values and assign to a new vector. I can get code to work for 1 column but I would like to use the `mapply` function or something similar to get the values across all the columns at the same time and assign to a new vector.

I have the following code for a single column

`myvector <- sum(na.omit(df[,2] - mean(df[,2))^2))`  this works for 1 column

I have tried the following for the whole dataframe

`myvector <- (mapply(na.omit(sum(df[,2:11] - mean(df[,2:11]))^2)))`

I get error saying "error in match.fun(FUN): c(""na.omit(sum(df[,2:11] - mean(df[, is not a function, character or symbol", 2:11]))^2 is not a function character or symbol

and

`myvector <- (mapply(sum(na.omit(df[,2:11] - mean(df[,2:11]))^2)))`

but get this error:

> Error in sum(na.omit, df[, 2:11] - mean(df[,  :
> invalid 'type' (closure) of argument
> In addition: Warning message:
> In mean.default(df[, 2:11]) :
> argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

My thought is that the na.omit is in the wrong place but I am lost as to where it should go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transpose the data, subtract column means, and then compute the sums of squares.

```
rowSums((t(df[-1]) - colMeans(df[-1], na.rm = TRUE))^2, na.rm = TRUE)
```

In addition, you can multiply the ***sample variance*** of each column and the respective length of non-missing values minus 1 to get sums of squared difference.

```
sapply(df[-1], var, na.rm = TRUE) * (colSums(!is.na(df[-1])) - 1)

# Lab1  Lab2  Lab3  lab4  lab5  lab6  lab7  lab8  lab9 lab10 
# 0.04  0.31  0.04  0.01  0.04  0.02  0.12  0.07  0.02  0.09
```

***Formula:*** [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `sapply` if you want to perform the operation column wise.

```
sapply(df[-1], function(x) sum((x - mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))^2, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Or using `colSums` and `colMeans` with `sweep` :

```
colSums(sweep(df[-1], 2, colMeans(df[-1], na.rm = TRUE)) ^ 2, na.rm = TRUE)

# Lab1  Lab2  Lab3  lab4  lab5  lab6  lab7  lab8  lab9 lab10 
# 0.04  0.31  0.04  0.01  0.04  0.02  0.12  0.07  0.02  0.09
```

Note that you can use `na.rm = TRUE` to ignore `NA` values.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(SampleNo = 1:6, Lab1 = c(59.84, 59.78, 59.86, 
59.85, 59.97, 60.03), Lab2 = c(60.59, 60.19, 60.17, 60.42, 60.79, 
60.26), Lab3 = c(60.39, 60.16, 60.22, 60.28, 60.3, 60.36), lab4 = c(60.29, 
60.23, 60.28, 60.31, 60.26, 60.21), lab5 = c(60.19, 60.32, 60.18, 
60.19, 60.4, 60.32), lab6 = c(60.32, 60.46, 60.42, 60.41, 60.47, 
60.46), lab7 = c(60.24, 60.53, 60.21, 60.54, 60.52, 60.5), lab8 = c(60.3, 
60.2, 60, 60.2, 60, 60.1), lab9 = c(60.43, 60.4, 60.44, 60.48, 
60.46, 60.29), lab10 = c(NA, 59.6, NA, 59.7, 59.7, 60)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```